# node.js: return boolean after callback

Tags: node.js, callback

I want to return a value in a function that I get from another function.
So for example:

```
var function1 = function(parameters) {
    let param1 = 1;
    let param2 = 2;

    returnValue = function2(param1, param2);
    console.log(returnValue);
    return returnValue;

}


var function2 = function(param1, param2) {
    if (param1 + param2 == 3) {
        return true; 
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The console.log always says "undefined" no matter what I try.
And I know that node.js is asynchronous and already does the log and return before a value is assigned so
I tried with callbacks and all that but I'm starting to think I don't really understand them cause nothing worked.
If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you provided is *not* operating asynchronously - also calling `function1()` logs `true`. Can you verify you've included the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with async and await

```
var function1 = async (parameters)=> {
  let param1 = 1;
  let param2 = 2;

  returnValue =  await function2(param1, param2);
  console.log(returnValue);
  return returnValue;

}


var function2 =  async (param1, param2) =>{
  if (param1 + param2 == 3) {

      return true; 
  }

  else {
      return false;
  }

}

function1();
```

[image: It will return true as expected]

Comment: Why use async/await here?

Comment: To wait for the second function executes. (unless it will execute sequentially) Look Synchronous And Asynchronous callbacks in nodejs or any language.

Comment: The provided function *does* execute synchronously, there's no need for async/await here. That is why I asked ...

Comment: No! I think you misunderstand about sequentially and synchronously. The provided function do execute in sequential manner.

Comment: function2 in the OP's post does not return a promise, it is absolutely unnecessary to wait for it, you can just directly use the return value! Just try it out with the code provided, it will log true just as expected  ...